# How to implement type checking in a Listener

Tags: antlr, antlr4

My script grammar contains the following:

```
if_statement
 : IF condition_block (ELSE IF condition_block)* (ELSE statement_block)?
 ;

condition_block
 : expression statement_block
 ;

expression
 : expression op=(LTEQ | GTEQ | LT | GT) expression  #relationalExpression
 | expression op=(EQ | NEQ) expression               #equalityExpression
 | expression AND expression                         #andExpression
 | expression OR expression                          #orExpression
 | atom                                              #atomExpression
 ;

atom
 : OPAR expression CPAR                                     #parenExpression
 | INT                                                      #numberAtom
 | (TRUE | FALSE)                                           #booleanAtom
 | STRING                                                   #stringAtom
 ;
```

What I would like to do, is to make sure that the user doesn't compare e.g. an INT to a STRING.

I use a Listener to provide errors to the user when they create a script. So what I want to do is something like

```
public override void EnterRelationalExpression([NotNull] ScriptEvaluatorParser.RelationalExpressionContext context)
{
    <..compare context.expression(0) to context.expression(1) here
     and add an error if not the same base type...>  
    base.EnterRelationalExpression(context);
}
```

Doing this in a Visitor is easy

```
object left = Visit(context.expression(0)
object right = Visit(context.expression(1)
<...compare types...>
```

But how do I do the same in the Listener? I can new up a Visitor and do it that way, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do the check without having to new up a Visitor.

Comment: I'd just use a visitor: it's the more intuitive solution for this use case IMO.

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve done this before by adding a type stack to my listener.

I use the exit*() listener hooks (you can’t really have any useful information about children in the enter*() methods, as the children have not been visited.

As an expression is exited,  I can determine the type directly, if it’s a simple type (or looking it’s type up in a symbol table if it’s an identifier).  Then push the type on the type stack.  For expressions like you `equalityExpression`, I pop the top two items from the type stack and check their compatibility (of course, it then pushes a `boolean` type on the type stack.

For `and` and `or` expressions, just pop the top two items, ensure they’re `boolean` and then push boolean.

This does depend on having a symbol table available to resolve identifier types, and is a bit of a work-around for listeners not returning values, but it has worked well for me.  I like the visitor handling the navigation and ensuring all nodes are visited.  But, as Bart mentions, if you’re comfortable with using visitors to accomplish this, there’s not really one way that’s “better” than another.

You can also look into adding locals to your rules to hold that resulting type.  This avoids the need for a type stack, and the management of that stack, but makes your grammar target language specific (which I like to avoid).  You’d still need to leverage the exit*() methods since children would have to be visited before the locals were populated (BTW, locals are just a way of adding additional fields to the ParseTreeContext for nodes.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up going the Visitor route as that worked well.

Comment: Side note: if you walk the tree (visit or listen) after a parse run, it doesn't really matter if you use the enter or exit methods. The tree exists, so all info is there. Only if you use a listener during the parse run it makes a difference.

Comment: Either I’m missing some your I have to disagree.  With the walker there’s no enter*/exit* decision to make, but you’ll need to visit the children to get the type info before you can evaluate. With a listener (using the type stack), you will need the children’s type info on the stack so you need the exit* methods (unless you drop down into the children to recursively examine them in the enter* method. Could be done, but not exactly the way one would recommend using a listener).  I suspect it’s much more likely that you are right and I’m wrong, but I’m just not seeing how