# How do I detect illegal expressions in antlr?

Tags: java, antlr

I use antlr [JavaParser](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java/JavaParser.g4).

```
expression
    : primary
    | expression bop='.'
      (
         identifier
       | methodCall
       | THIS
       | NEW nonWildcardTypeArguments? innerCreator
       | SUPER superSuffix
       | explicitGenericInvocation
      )
    | expression '[' expression ']'
    | methodCall
    | NEW creator
    | '(' annotation* typeType ('&' typeType)* ')' expression
    | expression postfix=('++' | '--')
    | prefix=('+'|'-'|'++'|'--') expression
    | prefix=('~'|'!') expression
    | expression bop=('*'|'/'|'%') expression
    | expression bop=('+'|'-') expression
    | expression ('<' '<' | '>' '>' '>' | '>' '>') expression
    | expression bop=('<=' | '>=' | '>' | '<') expression
    | expression bop=INSTANCEOF (typeType | pattern)
    | expression bop=('==' | '!=') expression
    | expression bop='&' expression
    | expression bop='^' expression
    | expression bop='|' expression
    | expression bop='&&' expression
    | expression bop='||' expression
    | <assoc=right> expression bop='?' expression ':' expression
    | <assoc=right> expression
      bop=('=' | '+=' | '-=' | '*=' | '/=' | '&=' | '|=' | '^=' | '>>=' | '>>>=' | '<<=' | '%=')
      expression
```

But some illegal expressions cannot be detected directly.

Such as `3 > 3 ? 3 : 45 : 45`, `2 > 3 > 4`.

[image]

I wonder how the java syntax detects such illegal expressions, it's extra coding work, or the ability to use antlr itself.

If it's extra coding work, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that from `3 > 3 ? 3 : 45 : 45` only `3 > 3 ? 3 : 45` is recognized as the expression (which is correct). If you'd test the parser with the extra rule:

```
single_expression
 : expression EOF
 ;
```

then the input `3 > 3 ? 3 : 45 : 45` will not be valid.

As for `2 > 3 > 4`: it *is* syntactically correct. To validate if it is semantically correct (which is not the work for a parser!), you'll need to implement type checking yourself. ANTLR's listener- and visitor classes can help, but the bulk of the work will have to be done by yourself. Also see [How to implement type checking in a Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185961/how-to-implement-type-checking-in-a-listener)